# Are there "smart pointers" in Java?

Tags: java, smart-pointers

Are there anything along the lines of C++ smart pointers in Java?

Comment: I think you may be confusing something there. Smart pointers are a wrapper around raw pointers that provide e.g. reference counting or bounds checking. Java doesn't have raw pointers and has GC built in.

Comment: See the Wikipedia explanation for smart pointers for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: The language implementation itself (the JVM) takes over most (if not all) the jobs usually handled by smart pointers in C++.

Comment: @garima, See https://vamppm1.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/smart-pointer-and-equivalent-in-java/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of Java's 'pointers' (references) are Smart Pointers.

Java is run in a managed environment.  Which means that Java uses a garbage collector to clean up variables that are no longer referenced any more.

Java's references are slightly different from pointers though.  Java abstracts away all of the pointer values and math that you see in C++.  So, anytime you create a new object and store it to a variable, you are storing it into Java's version of a 'smart pointer.'

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what's the difference between Java's references and C++'s smart pointers.

Comment: smart pointers give the developer control on when free and the destructor are called. For low latency programming, they eliminate "jitters" in response time that are common in Java.

auto pointers do that as well, and one better -- by putting the actual object on the stack rather than whatever part of the heap is available, they provide better locality.

Both are features I regret are unavailable in Java.

Comment: @MichaBerger when do  C++ smart pointers put actual objects on the stack?

Comment: Smart pointers don't put things anywhere. I misspoke back in May. I meant something more like: "auto pointers do that as well, and one better -- by LETTING THE PROGRAMMER PUT the actual object on the stack rather than whatever part of the heap is available, they provide better locality."

Answer (score 7):

I've only heard of smart pointers in the context of memory management. As memory management is at the core of the Java platform, there's obviously no need for that.

The closest matches that come to mind are java.lang.ref.WeakReference and java.lang.ref.SoftReference as they allow to customize garbage collection to some degree.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.  No in that, nothing like a pointer object exists in Java.  Yes in the sense that every object is a "smart pointer", meaning it's subjected to garbage collecting and takes care of its own lifetime so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no pointers of any class in Java. In general, you don't need *smart pointers* anyway because you already have a **garbage collector** in place doing reference counting to auto-manage memory allocation/release cycle.

Comment: @pablo-tx.. so only garbage collectors help in memory management?

Comment: This is not exactly true : an object in java **is** a pointer to the real resource.

Comment: @garima: not sure I understand you question, but YES: garbage collectors help in memory management.

Comment: @Valentin Rocher: it's definitely not a pointer (in the C/C++ way of using pointers). It's a reference. You don't have memory pointers in Java.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. This is clearer in my head, but clearly not in my comment. I think I'll delete it for the greater good.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz Java references look syntactically a little like C++ references, but their semantics are like pointers (although no arithmetic, obviously). In particular Java copies references by value.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: Yes. I was referring to Java references, not C++ references. Just clarified that, strictly speaking, Java does not have pointers (as in C/C++ pointers).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **deterministic destruction** or **reference counting**, which gives you timely control over object lifetime for the purpose of efficiently using resources (something which **garbage collection** does *not* give you), then Java offers two things.

1) The most common solution (used all over Java) is the `Closeable`/`AutoCloseable` pattern. It is a simple pattern. Each object that needs deterministic destruction has an owner, and the owner is responsible for calling `close`. (The object may have multiple users, but a single owner.) This is used for file handles, network sockets, etc.

2) A much rarer option is *reference counting*, where an object can have multiple owners (and typically, there is no clear distinction between users and owners). This is what C++ `shared_ptr` achieves. Look at [almson-refcount](https://github.com/almson/almson-refcount), which is a library I wrote that implements reference counting.

To clarify, deterministic destruction is necessary in Java when dealing with any kind of resource that *is not* memory. The garbage collector effectively manages memory with its lazy approach. However, you cannot rely on the garbage collector to manage any other resources. This is why `finalize` has been deprecated in Java 9.